# Single Sign On no redirecciona desde el servidor

Tags: c#, mvc, oauth2, single-sign-on

He Desarrollado un SSO usando OWIN y OAUTH2 para que los sitios WEB que estoy desarrollando todos pasen por el SSO, cuando levanto desde mi maquina (Desarrollo - Visual Studio) el SSO y cualquier otra app, inmediatamente llama el SSO y se autentica y concede los permisos para poder continuar todo funciona correctamente.

Pero cuando despliego el SSO al servidor y hago el llamado desde mi ambiente de desarrollo para la aplicación que estoy desarrollando sucede algo extraño.

1. Llama el SSO - (OK)
2. Se autentica - (OK)
3. No Redirecciona de nuevo a la pagina desde donde se llamó (localhost:xxxx/SomeApp) - (Bug)

NOTA: Pero si levanto los sitios desde el Visual Studio si funciona correctamente.

Espero que me puedas dar una mano con eso.. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué revertiste mi edición a tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar, y es que en el código fuente de Servidor AUTH tenia una linea de código donde bloqueaba la ejecución del mismo cuando no este usando direcciones seguras (HTTPS), mi servidor de pruebas no es SSL porque se una solo al interior de la entidad para poder hacer las pruebas pertinentes...

Lo que hice fue comentar esa linea mientras el ingeniero de infraestructura instala un certificado SSL en el sitio de pruebas.

Comment: podrías marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada ya que solucionó tu problema.